# What's the postinstall script in Visual Studio Code extensions for?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Many extensions for Visual Studio Code have the have the following in their `package.json`, including Microsoft's own [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/develop/package.json) extension:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
}
```

The `vscode` package is listed under `devDependencies`, but Visual Studio Code only installs `dependencies` (not `devDependencies`) when an extension is installed.

Since I haven't found an answer to this in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-manifest), I was hoping someone here could answer this: What is this script used for? When is it necessary to include it in my own extension manifest?

Comment: Could it be that it is run when developing the extension and doing `npm i`?

Answer (score 1):

That postinstall script is responsible for downloading the latest vscode.d.ts file

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2016/02/28/visual-studio-code-new-features-14-extension-authoring-improvements-api-consumption-quick-pick-octicons-virtual-documents-test-suite-for-debug-adapters-json-mode-extension-more/)